# How to archieve AOP in OSGi with Apache Felix

Tags: java, osgi, aop, aspectj, bnd

I'm currently working on an OSGi project where some parts are perfect for AOP programming. Without many experiences in AOP combined with OSGi, I would like to know how to best do AOP in an OSGi environment? I've read some articles about this problem, but did not find a solution that suits well for me. There is, for example, an Equinox Incubator project for AspectJ, but the last build was on 2008. But since I'm using Apache Felix and Bnd(tools) I want to avoid using something from Equinox. Btw., one requirement for the weaving process will be that it should be at compile-time and maybe later load-time as well. Furthermore I'm using Ant and Bnd to build my bundles. So it would be great if I can integrate Aspectj into this build process as well.

Hopefully someone can share experiences with such a use case.

**EDIT**

Summary so far:

- there is a possibility to use Spring AOP as Christian Schneider mentioned in his answer (but pityful not what I am looking for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can take a look at Aries JPA. Load time weaving was added recently there. Seems like there is also a weaving hook in the newer OSGi spec. So support for AspectJ and the like may be quite possible now. I have not yet seen it in action though.

A big question is of course. Why do you need AOP and what do you want to do with it?
In general AOP in most cases looks simpler than it is and gives you lees benefits than you think at first. So my advice is be careful and think twice before using AOP too much.

Comment: hi Christian. Thx for your reply. In my opinion Aries is more suitable for JPA use cases where you are working with datasources. But to be honest maybe it solve an other problem, so nevertheless thx for mention it ;) About AOP: One case where I want to use it will be many of the standard logging processes. Furthermore, some security issues are a perfectly match for it as well. Of course I could solve it without using aspects, but it would be great to avoid redundant/bad code. But you are right, I have to be careful to not overuse AOP.

Comment: I strongly advise to not use full AOP as it gets out of control easily. What works very well is using aspects on classes that are injected using interfaces. In that case you can use dynamic proxies instead of bytecode manipulation. For example spring allows to do security, logging and transactions on interface boundaries. This then works very nicely in OSGi too. I personally never needed to use more than that. The only exception is jpa but there are specialized libs for these cases.

Comment: Could you provide a link for more description?

Comment: For spring dm it is basically just the normal config like described in the spring documentation. See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html
In chapter 6.1.3 they describe that spring uses dynamic proxies by default. These work great in OSGi as they need no weaving.

Comment: Hi. The last days I was trying to get behind your proposal of using Spring AOP. First it looks good since it is not AOP directly, Spring uses dynamic proxies as you mentioned before. But it has some limitations in having no bean classes. In my case I do not want to add full Spring support to my environment so I dont want to have bean specifications and some xml who defines them. So I think with this, Spring is not what I was looking for. Do you have some other proposals for me?